# TextInputLayout change border color when it contains text

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I want to change the `TextInputLayout` Box color when it contains some text or maintained the focused state when contains the text.

My Code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/et_email_layout"
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
   android:hint="@string/email"
   android:textColorHint="@color/grey_40"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_url_layout">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/et_email"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
      android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_email"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
      android:maxLength="20"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:paddingStart="10dp"
      android:paddingEnd="10dp"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/color_text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

OutPut:

[image]

When Focused:

[image]

UnFocus:

[image]

I want to achieve the same state of focus when it does contains some text.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in detail your question we didn't get it

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology I'm trying to have a state of focus when it does contains the text. Like: If the `TextInputEditText` contains some text then change the borderBox color of `TextInputLayout`